# What should I do on exceptions thrown by SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait

Tags: java, swing, multithreading

`SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait()` throws an `InterruptedException` and an `InvocationTargetException` how should I handle these?

```
 public static void invokeAndWait(Runnable doRun) throws InterruptedException,
                                 InvocationTargetException
```

I want to use the method to show a dialog and wait for the user to say yes or no. As far as I can tell the `InvocationTargetException` means there was a `RuntimeException` and I can treat it like that. However what I would really want for the `InterruptedException` is to ignore it and have thread continue until the user has given an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

InterruptedException is explained in this [article](https://web.archive.org/web/20160617013453/http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05236/index.html).

The InvocationTargetException, it's thrown if the Runnables run method throws an exception.

Maybe running this example clarifies things:

```
        try {
        SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("1");
                if (true) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("runtime exception");
                }
                System.out.println("2");
            }
        });
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(System.out);
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }
```

Comment: An `InterruptedException` means the *calling* thread was interrupted, not the EDT.

Comment: Does this mean that the `Runnable` given to 'invokeAndWait' doesn't get executed anymore?

Comment: Article link is dead.

Comment: Artice link is live (again). :) 
"Java theory and practice: Dealing with InterruptedException"

Comment: article is dead (again). [Archived link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160617013453/http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05236/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

An InterruptedException while showing a dialog box would be extremely rare.  You could ignore it, or try displaying the dialog again by calling invokeAndWait on a new Runnable again.

If the dialog is being called as standalone (i.e. not as part of the main GUI), using invokeAndWait is fine.  However if you are displaying the dialog from within the EDT, you might not want to use invokeAndWait.  More details here:  [Concurrency in Swing](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

Comment: This is a partial answer. Say I want to show a dialog from worker thread #1, then I call invokeAndWait. Then, if worker thread #2 comes in and tells the system that the dialog is no longer necessary, then this thread interrupts worker thread #1, which will thus now be required to handle the InterruptedException thrown by invokeAndWait. What I do, for example, is catching the exception, dispose the dialog (on an invokeLater, this time), and upthrow the exception. So the use case is perfectly valid and pretty clean imho. I do not agree with the statement of your first sentence.